# Pandas: select multiple rows or default with new API

Tags: pandas

I need to retrieve multiples rows (which could be duplicated) and if the index does not exist get a default value. An example with Series:

```py
s = pd.Series(np.arange(4), index=['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
labels = ['a', 'd', 'f']
result = s.loc[labels]
result = result.fillna(my_default_value)
```

Now, I'm using DataFrame, an equivalent with names is:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Person": {
        "name_1": "Genarito",
        "name_2": "Donald Trump",
        "name_3": "Joe Biden",
        "name_4": "Pablo Escobar",
        "name_5": "Dalai Lama"
    }
})

default_value = 'No name'
names_to_retrieve = ['name_1', 'name_2', 'name_8', 'name_3']
result = df.loc[names_to_retrieve]
result = result.fillna(default_value)
```

With both examples it's throwing a warning saying:

> FutureWarning:  Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing
> label will raise KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an
> alternative.

In the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated) of the issue it says that you should use `reindex` but they say that It won't work with duplicates...

Is there any way to work without warnings and duplicated indexes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `merge`:

```
result = (pd.DataFrame({'label':labels})
            .merge(s.to_frame(name='x'), left_on='label', 
                   right_index=True, how='left')
            .set_index('label')['x']
         )
```

Output:

```
label
a    0.0
a    1.0
d    NaN
f    NaN
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your answer! If you could make the equivalent of your solution for DataFrames I would appreciate it, otherwise no problem, it's my fault for not having left an example with DataFrames (there I just edited my question) and clarify that i was using them explicitly

Comment: @Genarito For DataFrame it's easier, just replace `s.to_frame(name='x')` (which i had to put their to return `s` into a dataframe) with your dataframe and remove the last `['x']`.

Comment: You're the best! I'll make some comparisons in terms of performance and i'll mark the accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How about :

```py
on_values = s.loc[s.index.intersection(labels).unique()]
off_values = pd.Series(default_value,index=s.index.difference(labels))
result = pd.concat([on_values,off_values])
```

Comment: This works if the order of `labels` is not important. +1 still.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your answer! If I try it with DataFrames it returns two columns, one with the `default_value` in missing indexes and others with NaN. If you could make the equivalent of your solution for DataFrames I would appreciate it, otherwise no problem, it's my fault for not having left an example with DataFrames (there I just edited my question)

Comment: @Genarito change `pd.Series(...)` to `pd.DataFrame(default_value, index=..., columns=df.columns)`.

Comment: Thank you again @QuangHoang!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple function to handle the rows in labels and missing from labels separately, then join. When `True` the `in_order` argument will ensure that if you specify `labels = ['d', 'a', 'f']`, the output is ordered `['d', 'a', 'f']`.

```
def reindex_with_dup(s: pd.Series or pd.DataFrame, labels, fill_value=np.NaN, in_order=True):
    labels = pd.Series(labels)

    s1 = s.loc[labels[labels.isin(s.index)]]
    
    if isinstance(s, pd.Series):
        s2 = pd.Series(fill_value, index=labels[~labels.isin(s.index)])
    if isinstance(s, pd.DataFrame):
        s2 = pd.DataFrame(fill_value, index=labels[~labels.isin(s.index)],
                          columns=s.columns)
        
    s = pd.concat([s1, s2])

    if in_order:
        s = s.loc[labels.drop_duplicates()]

    return s


reindex_with_dup(s, ['d', 'a', 'f'], fill_value='foo')
#d    foo
#a      0
#a      1
#f    foo
#dtype: object
```

---

This retains the `.loc` behavior that if your index is duplicated **and** your labels are duplicated it duplicates the selection:

```
reindex_with_dup(s, ['d', 'a', 'a', 'f', 'f'], fill_value='foo')
#d    foo
#a      0
#a      1
#a      0
#a      1
#f    foo
#f    foo
#dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `isin` with append

```
out = s[s.index.isin(labels)]
out = out.append(pd.Series(index=set(labels)-set(s.index),dtype='float').fillna(0))
out
Out[341]: 
a    0.0
a    1.0
d    0.0
f    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your answer! If I try it with DataFrames it returns two columns, one with the `default_value` in missing indexes and others with NaN. If you could make the equivalent of your solution for DataFrames I would appreciate it, otherwise no problem, it's my fault for not having left an example with DataFrames (there I just edited my question)